# Neo4j-Cypher : Get playlist and list of songs in each playlist in 1 query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph which contains users, playlists and songs they have added in each playlist. The schema looks like this:

```
(user)--HAS_LIST-->(playlist1)--HAS_SONG-->(song1)
  |                     |
  |                     --------HAS_SONG-->(song2)
  |
  ------HAS_LIST-->(playlist2)--HAS_SONG-->(song3)
```

I have a use case where I am displaying all the playlists a user has (say I limit it at 10 playlists per query) . While doing so, I wanna show him images of the first 2 songs and the count of the number of songs in the playlist. Is there a way to do this in 1 cypher query ?

I use Neo4j 1.9

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it is possible in 1.9

Not sure if we had subscripts there.

something like this:

```
start user = ..
match (user)-[:HAS_LIST]->(playlist)-[:HAS_SONG]->(song)
RETURN playlist, collect(song.title)[0..2] as prevew, count(*) as songs
```

Otherwise you have to simulate them with `[head(songs), head(tail(songs))] as preview`

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks (again). This works for me, except that it does not return playlists without any songs. Is there a way to capture null collections as well ?